# Symbol Script for Breast Cancer Ribbon

Tags: facebook, unicode

I have Windows Vista 32 bit with Javascript. I am a four time breast cancer survivor who uses Facebook for support, awareness, education and spreading positivity and my love of God. I would very much like to add an Awareness Ribbon to my username. I've seen others with Greek symbols in theirs. It's just a little ribbon and I've been searching for months.

Is it possible, I am not using the correct terminology when searching the web? If not, please suggest what words I should be using.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of the specific unicode symbol that represents what you are talking about, but there are several options:

- You could use a tool such as http://people.w3.org/rishida/scripts/uniview/ and try to find the character by using the "Show Range" filter on the top right. Then click the button immediately to its right. There are a lot of categories, and even more characters per category, so it might take a while.
- If you have ever seen this character used, you should be able to highlight it and copy and paste it wherever you like.

Here's another site that lets you browse the Unicode chars by category: http://www.unicode.org/charts/index.html. However, this uses PDF, so it might take even more time to find what you want.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't Unicode allow you to combine characters to form a unified one? Couldn't you find the two parts of what looks like a ribbon and combine them to form a single character?

Update: The closest Unicode chars I found are: [ɣ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_fricative), [ɤ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_unrounded_vowel)

Answer (score 2):

U+1F397 was added to Unicode in version 7.0 (2014). [source](https://codepoints.net/U+1F397?lang=en) It is called REMINDER RIBBON. ￼It can either be copied and pasted from the previous link, or in Windows you can use the `Alt`+`1F397`. There is also an [emoji reminder ribbon](http://emojipedia.org/unicode-7.0/) - again depending on Unicode version 7. This doesn't seem supported yet in facebook or by most browsers.

[image]

Given the facebook 'real name' policy is likely to force those using special characters in their names to change them, it seems best to use the ribbon for your profile picture instead.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is "unicode characters."

I do not know if there is a character that looks like a ribbon.  There is a bow-tie, it looks like this: ⋈

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Webdings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdings) but this is not part of the [unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) set.
[image]

Comment: Just some clarification for @Yvette: Since Facebook chooses the font that the title is displayed in, and because they didn't choose Webdings, you won't be able to use any of these characters. Your only option is to find a character in the Unicode set, since Unicode is not a font, so it doesn't matter which font Facebook chose. I hope that makes sense.